# Dynamic Parameters of one jenkins job is to be picked up automatically by other jenkins job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow

I have a jenkins job A to select any choices from parameters while building job , the same parameters values that i have selected on job A  should be picked by job B automatically every time when  i try to build job B . Where job B should not be downstream job of job A.

My workaround: I tried to copy the parameters that i select on job A to a file .

On job B ,i was unable to find the option in jenkins, to select the variable value to be picked up from a file in parameters section.

Any suggestions and different approaches will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using a System Groovy script.  You find the most recent job A build, and copy the parameter values into Job B.

```
import hudson.model.*
def hif = Hudson.instance

  //Get build variables for this build
def buildMap = build.getBuildVariables() 

//get most recent build of project A
def a = hif.getItems(hudson.model.Project).find {it.displayName.toUpperCase()=='PROJECT A'}.getBuilds().first()

//Add parameter to the build variables for this build
buildMap['MYPARAM']=a.buildVariableResolver.resolve('MYPARAM')
println(buildMap['MYPARAM'])


//Assign the new parameters back to job B
setBuildParameters(buildMap)

def setBuildParameters(map) {
    def npl = new ArrayList<StringParameterValue>()
    for (e in map) {
        npl.add(new StringParameterValue(e.key.toString(), e.value.toString()))
    }
    def newPa = null
    def oldPa = build.getAction(ParametersAction.class)
    if (oldPa != null) {
        build.actions.remove(oldPa)
        newPa = oldPa.createUpdated(npl)
    } else {
        newPa = new ParametersAction(npl)
    }
    build.actions.add(newPa)
}
```